# The techniques to prevent spam posts in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spam-prevention

Is there any technique to prevent spam post before active record saves its record.
I was just thinking of putting before_filter, in which it judges if the registered keyword is included in parameters past,and it forces to redirect.

Is it normal way? or it slows down the system teribbly as the spam keywords get more?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a service like Akismet through one of these gems:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/spam_detection